# What is the Operating System on Google Home Device?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

The [Verge article](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/5/31/11822032/google-home-chromecast-android) states

> Google Home is based on Chromecast, not Android

I have a few queries, if someone tried the following on a Google Home device?

- Is fastboot supported?
- Is ADB supported?
- What are the partitions on the on-board NAND Flash?
- What libraries are seen in the root image?

Comment: Google have previously claimed it is a simplified version of Chrome OS, but a team of hackers that picked the device apart have apparently claimed its more android-based than being Chrome OS, and appears to heavily leverage software taken from Google TV. This probably doesn't help you much, but that's the history I know of.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I can answer only two of the queries:

First two get answer "No, they aren't supported."

The guy in [this reddit article](https://www.google.fi/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/googlehome/comments/5c5tfi/poking_at_the_google_home/) played with one Google home device and found that out.

There is a hidden usb port in machine, but both ADB nor fastboot don't work.

Wireless abd tries to connect some IP but IP remained offline despite efforts of pushing device buttons. That's why I consider it also not supported.

Sorry, this is only a partial answer.