# Can I install Mycroft on Google Home?

Tags: google-home, open-source, mycroft

I have been given a Google Home from a contest at work. I think it would be very useful if it didn't spy on my every word. I wonder if I can wipe the installed Chrome OS it is based on and install Mycroft instead.  Open source all the way!  Is this possible?

I understand there is a hidden USB port in the back: would this help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google home indeed has a hidden port inside it. But actually there is no evidence that it supports Fastboot and ADB. So hopes are narrow as of now to install a new OS on google home.
[Refer here](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/what-is-the-operating-system-on-google-home-device)